# Making multiple vectors one single vector in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I have a company logo in vector repeated multiple times to make a pattern/background. I want to apply a halftone to it, but to do so I need to make all the repeated vectors into one single vector. I have tried all of the pathfinder options with no luck and making a compound path messes up the logo (fills in the hole in the "a"). Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: The pathfinder tools would normally be the way to achieve this, what happens when you try to `Unite` the paths, does it give you an error message?

Comment: @JacksonHyde no error, just incorrect results. http://i.imgur.com/FduZ5q5.jpg

Comment: Have you tried `Object > Compound Path > Make`, and then apply the gradient?

Answer (score 6):

Select all and use `Pathfinder > Merge`.

This will combine all shapes which are the same color and touch.

Afterwards, you may have undesired white objects. Simply select one white object and choose `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke` and hit <kbd>delete</kbd>.

### Based on the comments below, I need to highlight this method....

- Select all
- **Group**
- apply a **new fill** via the **Appearance Panel**
- set that fill to be a gradient
- If needed, drag the new fill above the `contents` item in the **Appearance Panel**

Comment: Merge does the same as unite, adds in and unwanted fill in the "a" - http://i.imgur.com/FduZ5q5.jpg

Comment: Then your art has some issues. It should be expanded completely before using the merge command.

Comment: after expanding the merge works without filling in the "a", but it does not seem to become "one" vector. I need to apply a gradient but when I do after the merge every single logo gets its own gradient and I need the gradient to spread across all logos

Comment: To apply one gradient over everything... select it all, add the gradient, then use the **Gradient Tool** to click-drag the gradient.

Comment: Yes, and I may be going about that incorrectly

Comment: You could also simply **Group** everything and apply a new fill via the **Appearance Panel** and set that fill to be a gradient.

Answer (score 4):

Select all and use `Object > Compound Path > Make`

Just a different method to use. It keeps all the objects individual instead of merging them.

Comment: making it a compound path yields the same result as unite! - http://i.imgur.com/FduZ5q5.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If your text is still "text", release it all by highlighting everything and then go `Type > Create Outlines`.

Then, with everything selected, use `Object > Expand`

Finally go to pathfinder and choose the `Unite` tool to turn it into "one" vector:

[image]

Comment: my text was already outlined. Did object > expand, then unite, results in "a" being filled for some reason? http://i.imgur.com/FduZ5q5.jpg

Comment: That would be because the bowl in your A was already filled in white. You should of removed it before your copied your logo about 500 times.

Comment: @Saturneye Thanks for the helpful tone, but I did already remove it before I copied it 500 times

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you group images
then make a clipping mask
and a gradient over that?

This way you can change anything you need to at a later date as well easily

Answer (score 1):

An interesting conundrum. In this situation, I might try Pathfinder on one instance of the logo, get that right, then create the pattern and merge, but you're well past that point. At this stage, I don't see messing with paths as productive.

You want to end up with a half-tone of a particular size or a small range of sizes, so there isn't really a need to retain everything as vector information. Instead, export what you have as TIFF(s) or PNG of appropriate size, create a new document, import the raster image and apply the half-tone to that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `Pathfinder` and performing a `Divide` first. This will make sure that overlapping areas are simplified. In particular it will make sure that the counter of the "a" (the enclosed part) is knocked out from the black area, which I seem to understand is what is giving you trouble.

Then, after divided, you could select all black objects (select one then, as Scott suggested, use `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke` and using the `Pathfinder` again perform a `Unite`. You can also delete the white or empty (no fill) objects.

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is still reading this thread years in the future like myself, I found something that worked for me after experiencing a similar problem. I made sure my two objects were *ungrouped* and *expanded* them. Then I selected **Object > Compound Path > Make**. I applied my gradient and voila! The gradient stretched across the two separate objects rather than creating two separate gradients.

Comment: Sorry, that solution was mentioned several times above. I was trying several different things in Illustrator, found my solution, and got a little too excited to post and didn't notice the answer had been given already.

Comment: If the solution was already stated you can delete your answer by clicking the delete link.  Keep in mind that duplicating answers that are already present tends to receive downvotes and gets flagged for removal.